# Return of .shift() is possibly undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing a TypeScript function and my IDE is telling me, that the result of .shift() is possibly undefined, which leads to more type warnings down the road...

Here is the code:

```
function accumulateProofs(
  proofs: Proof[],
  requiredAmount: Number,
  strategy: 'middle' | 'ascending' | 'descending',
): Proof[] {
  const result:Proof[] = [];
  const temp = proofs.slice();
  let total = 0;
  switch (strategy) {
    case 'middle': {
      while (temp.length && total < desired) {
        const first = temp.shift();
        total += first.amount;
        result.push(first);
        if (total >= desired) {
          break;
        }
        const last = temp.pop();
        total += last;
        result.push(last);
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Now I understand that this warning makes sense, when you can't be sure that an array has any elements in it, in which case .shift() would return undefined. But in this case my while-loop only is running if temp.length is truthy, in which case I know that temp.shift() will return a value and not undefined... Am I missing something?

Comment: `temp.shift() as Proof`

Comment: If your array is empty, `shift` will return undefined, so you can check is the array contains at least one element : `while (temp.length && temp.length > 0 && total < desired)`. You should also type you array to indicate to the transpiler that it can't contains `undefined` value

Comment: `temp.length` already checks that the array is not empty. `temp.length > 0` would be superfluous.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), showing the problem. Pasting  [your code](https://tsplay.dev/ND81jN) gives a lot of errors.

Comment: Lazy solution: `//@ts-ignore` ;)

Comment: `temp.shift()!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shift` is defined as generic method of `Array` and have the following signature:

`Array<T>.shift(): T | undefined`

so it doesn't matter if your code assert against `temp.length` or not, the moment you call the `shift` you have to expect as return type:

`T | undefined`

you just have to add a default value:

```
const first = temp.shift() || { amount: 0 }
```

and the same is true for `temp.pop()`.

here is a link to [ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=52&pln=16&pc=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYZsg3gWAChlk4BbDAV3AC5kRKyAjaIgXyJmoTGAxFIIEjSgBs4kdFhgBnABRESAB0zYZdKdgDaAXQA0i5FAgBHSsGMATAIIVqYOgDlGLKAeLIZYKBIgBzAE86AHIyYEtLUQhg5AAfZGC4GSQQS1A-GPjgywhkiFT04PcASg1VGF08QwR%20L2QcmQsIS2QAXmQARgAGLoBuatqwI1yxBzRyyvbdfo8akDrIMiU25BVpGQA6GVFgJDlimZIoobAMMDhRFb7DGQB3YDAEAAtkOS8fSEDiqo8SBCSUKFwpFonQCL8SMhbk9gFFXoslBsoiA-GAXgAydHIU7nS4AHnquSalm%204Mh5OQczqMAsdXaCK2MJgYH2cXiuFIdloyC6yDYhwpJBxF2QAGp2jSoF4NuQqOABYLjDJRhslJQZE85JKvAdDILgDg5MLLgA%20doNYmkvWC5BMYxwADWCopHAh5KpQ3EdOxECWqowSlZsXZnLlY15-Ot5ONYvaXrAMq5YGd5KVKrVGrk8d1br51tdJALwzAlCgAjTojA7CAA)

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! However TS also complains about the next line ```result.push(first);``` as result is typed to be Proof[]. So I guess I'll have to go for ! operators here